# Laravel Eloquent: keeping all interactions with a model in sync in two different databases

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, database-connection

I am working on a standard Laravel project (with a single MySQL database).

Now I need to keep in sync **only one** of my tables with another remote database. Thus, every change: *creation*, *update*, *deletion*, etc. in that specific table should be propagated / reproduced to the remote one in real time.

I have Googled before asking, but I haven't found a smart way to do it in **Laravel** apart from the obvious method which implies making every DB transaction to that model / table on both database connections.

By the way, I have seen the `connection` protected property of Eloquent ORM which sets a default DB connection for a specific model, but I am looking for *something like having an array* of values in that `connection` property.

No luck so far.
Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making all queries on eloquent models, then you could utilise eloquent events.

Inside your event listener/observer, you could clone the model and change the connection on the cloned model so that you can execute the query on the second database.

Comment: I had not thought in Laravel events system, thanks. Your solution is good enough because that would let me centralize all of that logic in one single place, which is what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: Just for the record, when implementing the solution, I have found a *nice* shortcut that I want to share with you: it consists in just defining **two different models**, each one with a `protected connection` property pointing to each one of the databases. Later, in my event listener, I just need to **replicate** one of them into the other and save the second one (`https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#replicating-models`). Two lines of code :)

Comment: @andcl instead of creating two models, you can just change the connection dynamically before replicating the instance via `modelInstance->setConnection()`

Comment: Good observation, then even more optimized, thanks! It sums up to perform the following actions in the event listener:
`modelInstance->setConnection('db2');`
`modelInstance->save();`